# remove extra space, line breaks and $nbsp from a string javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, trim

how can I turn this

```
\n            <!DOCTYPE html >\n            <html>\n                <body>\n                <p>test&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>\n                <select multiple=\"multiple\">\n                    <option value=\"1\" correct=\"true\">red</option><option value=\"2\" correct=\"false\">Blue</option>\n                </select>\n                <p visible-if=\"correct\">Yeah correct</p>\n                <p visible-if=\"wrong\">Wrong dude</p>\n                </body>\n            </html>\n
```

into this

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><p>test</p><select multiple="multiple"> <option value="1" correct="true">red</option><option value="2" correct="false">Blue</option></select><p visible-if="correct">Yeah correct</p><p visible-if="wrong">Wrong dude</p></body></html>
```

using **javascript** ?

I've tried following code. but could not get this to work

```
.replace(/\r?\n?\s+/g, '').trim();
```

Comment: What was the result of your attempt?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit here the result https://pastebin.com/hzVTcnZd

Comment: Why do you think it turned out like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexes are incorrect.

Example output from Node.js CLI:

```javascript
> "\n ... your string here ... </html>\n".replace(/[\r\n]/g, '').replace(/\s+/g, ' ').replace(/ >/g, '>').replace(/> </g, '><').trim()
'<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><p>test&nbsp;&nbsp;</p><select multiple="multiple"><option value="1" correct="true">red</option><option value="2" correct="false">Blue</option></select><p visible-if="correct">Yeah correct</p><p visible-if="wrong">Wrong dude</p></body></html>'
```

You should get the gist how to add more cleanup code...

In short: don't try to squeeze everything into one regex.

Comment: thanks @Stefan Becker this code work for me I just added a few more code
`str.replace(/\s+/g, ' ').replace(/&nbsp;/gi,'').replace(/ >/g, '>').replace(/> </g, '><').trim();`

Comment: Sorry noticed that the regex in the first replace() didn't work. FIXED

Comment: @Aslam if it helped you should consider upvoting and accepting answer. +1 from my side mate.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will make the trick:

```
let result = null;
let input = `     <!DOCTYPE html >  
<html>             <body>`;

result = input.replace(/\s+((?=\<)|(?=$))/g, '');
```

It will respect everything inside html markup, but erases every space, tab, carriage return, etc. outside of it.

You can see it working [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/Z9RnGD/1).

Answer (score 1):

This regex will help.

`\s+([<>])` - Matches any space before `<` or `>`

`&nbsp;` - Macthes `&nbsp;`.

`([<>]\s+)` - Matches any `<` or `>` followed by space.

```js
let str = `'\n            <!DOCTYPE html >\n            <html>\n                <body>\n                <p>test&nbsp;&nbsp;</p>\n                <select multiple=\"multiple\">\n                    <option value=\"1\" correct=\"true\">red</option><option value=\"2\" correct=\"false\">Blue</option>\n                </select>\n                <p visible-if=\"correct\">Yeah correct</p>\n                <p visible-if=\"wrong\">Wrong dude</p>\n                <  /body>\n            </html>\n';`

let op = str.replace(/\s+([<>])|&nbsp;|([<>])\s+/g, "$1$2")

console.log(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a single regex: `/\r?\n?\s\s+|\s+(?=>)|&nbsp;/g`.

The only possible issue here is that it won't remove single whitespace after a `<` like in `< !doctype>`, but neither do the answers we got here so far. You could have it covered if js supported *positive look behinds*, just add `|(?<=<)\s+` to the regex.

Btw, this is a great place to test regexes: https://regexr.com